# yii2 urlmanager rules conflict

Tags: module, yii2, yii-url-manager

i use below code for url manager in Yii2 Framework :

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<module:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/default/<action>'
        ]
    ],
```

but. when enable the rule that remove default from url for modules , the rule for controllers stops working.

where the problem is my code?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is - your module rule overriders controller one.
The `<module>` and `<controller>` are not a keywords for UrlManager, so - in your case it does not works.
Your Url-config should be like that:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+><action:\w+>' => '<module>/default/<action>'
    ]
],
```

It will use the `default` controller any time. Do you really want it? 
It is better to use just `'<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+><action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>'`

Comment: i want to remove controller name from url . by your solation "default"  name in come back!